# Restrict Process access to certain USB devies

Tags: windows, usb, permissions

Is it possible to restrict a process on my system to have access to only a specific USB device connected to the system?

i.e.

```
USB DEVICES  PROCESSES
A B C        1 2 3
-
Access Rules:
A->1 but not 2 and 3
B->2 but not 1 and 3
C->3 but not 1 and 2
```

Comment: What type of USB devices?

Comment: @Robert USB data gateway devices, for example debugging/programming devices

Comment: One possibility would be to jail each process in an own virtual machine and forward one USB into each VM. If there is a possibility without VMs I don't know. I would assume that this also depends on the driver used by the USB devices if it is possible to assign permissions to device instances.